# Дорожная карта изучения Java/Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, карты

Мне 30 лет, работаю не в сфере программирования. Изучал PHP самостоятельно, писал простые сайты или там NodeMCU (Arduino) плата для умного дома + обработка get запросов на сервере для ведения статистики. Сейчас решил воплотить мечту и стать Андроид разработчиком. Общее понимание программирования и алгоритмов есть. Выработал для себя следующую дорожную карту, но имеются вопросы:

1. Курс JavaRush: Java Syntax + Java Syntax pro (прошел)
2. Курс JavaRush: Java Core
3. Курс Udacity(JavaRush): Android Development for Beginners - By Udacity (прошел, но повторю)
4. Курс Udacity:Udacity - Android Basics Nanodegree by Google nd803 v1.0.0

Вопросы:
1. Правильное ли выбрал направление?
2. На каком этапе стоит переходить на Kotlin (либо же учить его параллельно с JAVA)
3. Чтобы вы исправили или посоветовали?

Спасибо!

Comment: Ну, если уж вы хотите субъективного мнения, то мой в том, что курсы не нужны. Читайте учебники.

Comment: советую как можно раньше начинать реальные проекты. клиент-серверные приложения, работа с б/д, только найдите на гитхабе приложения с хорошей архитектурой mvvm или mvp и по ним делайте. учитесь сразу писать правильно

Comment: еще изучите RxJava, корутины для асинхронной работы и DI(советую Koin). Kotlin учите сразу. без него никак

Comment: Спасибо за советы! Вопрос немного о другом: если предположить, что курсы идут по учебнику + читаю учебник Герберт Шилдт - Java для начинающих, приступать ли к КОТЛИН, когда, и что дополнительно требуется, чтобы полноценно получить должность junior android. А также есть ли перспектива в Андроид разработке чисто на Java (вопрос более философский и не для того, чтобы не учить Котлин).

Comment: все новые проекты пишутся на котлин

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/461877/

Answer (score 2):

Вот есть хорошая дорожная карта https://github.com/mobile-roadmap/android-developer-roadmap

Kotlin учить однозначно стоит. Большинство новых проектов пишут на Kotlin